Unital Ring $R$ (Commutativity Not Assumed) is a Field if and only if Maximal Ideal is $0$.
I have only seen this statement proven under the assumption that $R$ is commutative. However, what if we dropped this assumption? (And before somebody comments this, I am aware that the ring will have to be commutative in order to be a field. I ask this so as to potentially strengthen the statement, dropping the need for confirming commutativity.) See the proof I've got written below:
Proof. Assume ring $R$ has maximal ideal $0$. Then for any $u\in R$, it follows $(u)=R$. Noting that $(u)=R\{u\}R$, we deduce there exist $a,b\in R$ such that $aub=1$. If we assume $u$ is not a unit, then $au$ must not be a unit, creating a contradiction. Therefore, we conclude that $u\in R^{\times}$ must be a unit. ✓ The converse case is no different from the case in which $R$ is assumed to be commutative, hence we know this direction to be true. ✓ From this, we conclude that in fact yes, unital ring $R$ is a field if and only if $R$ has trivial maximal ideal.
Everything looks good...but sometimes these conclusions aren't always correct. I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Edit. After having reviewing the provided responses, below is a summary of all the errors.
Proof Revision. Assume ring $R$ has maximal ideal $0$. Then for any $u\in R$, it follows $(u)=R$. Noting that $(u)=R\{u\}R$, we deduce there exist $a,b\in R$ such that $aub=1$. (This is incorrect.) If we assume $u$ is not a unit, then $au$ must not be a unit (This is incorrect: The assumption was that $a$ would need be a unit, in which case the conclusion would be correct. But it's possible $a$ may not be a unit, so no such conclusion of this sort may be reached), creating a contradiction. Therefore, we conclude that $u\in R^{\times}$ must be a unit. ✓

Why wouldn’t $au$ be a unit if $u$ isn’t?

And your note is incorrect as the set you describe isn’t closed for addition.

@Maxime I made the assumption that $a\in R$ must be a unit...why? I'm not entirely sure...probably an error, though I'll look into it.


Noting that $(u)=R\{u\}R$, we deduce there exist $a,b\in R$ such that $aub=1$.

This step is incorrect. The two-sided ideal generated by $u$ is not the set of elements of $R$ of the form $\{ aub : a, b \in R \}$, because unlike the left or right or commutative case, this set of elements is not closed under addition. Instead it is the span of the set of such elements, so you can only write $\sum a_i u b_i = 1$ for some $a_i, b_i$ and then the rest of your argument can't get off the ground.
(Also, this is more minor, but you don't establish commutativity so you don't seem to be aware that noncommutative  division rings exist, but they do.)
In fact the claim is false in the noncommutative case. Rings with no nontrivial two-sided ideals (equivalently, where the zero ideal is maximal as a two-sided ideal) are called simple rings and there are many examples that aren't commutative and hence are not fields, such as division rings, matrix rings $M_n(K)$ over fields, or the Weyl algebra. The last two classes of examples aren't division rings.
The matrix ring $M_n(K)$ provides an explicit counterexample to the claim about two-sided ideals above: it's a nice linear algebra exercise to show that if $M \in M_n(K)$ is a matrix of rank $r$ then the set $\{ XMY : X, Y \in M_n(K) \}$ consists exactly of the matrices of rank $\le r$. Since every matrix can be written as the sum of matrices of rank $1$, it follows that the two-sided ideal generated by $M$ is all of $M_n(K)$ unless $r = 0$, or equivalently $M = 0$.
In a positive direction, what can be said in the noncommutative case is that a left Artinian simple ring $R$ is semisimple (see here), hence by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem is a matrix ring $M_n(D)$ over a division ring. Alternatively, if you instead require that the zero ideal is maximal as a left resp. right ideal, then $R$ is simple as a left resp. right module over itself, hence is a division algebra by Schur's lemma, together with "Cayley's theorem for rings."

Edit:

If we assume $u$ is not a unit, then $au$ must not be a unit, creating a contradiction. Therefore, we conclude that $u\in R^{\times}$ must be a unit.

As you've remarked, this step is, separately, also incorrect, but it's worth seeing an explicit counterexample. That is, it's possible for $aub = 1$ but for $u$ to not be a unit, and in fact $u$ does not have to be either left or right invertible.
For an explicit counterexample, let $R$ be the ring of endomorphisms of a countable-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $K$. We can think of $V$ explicitly as being the vector space of sequences $(s_1, s_2, \dots )$ with finitely many nonzero entries. Let $u \in R$ be the map
$$(s_1, s_2, s_3, \dots) \mapsto (0, s_2, s_3, \dots )$$
which deletes the first term. Then $u$ is neither injective nor surjective, so is neither left- nor right-invertible in $R$. Now let $b \in R$ be the right shift
$$(s_1, s_2, s_3, \dots) \mapsto (0, s_1, s_2, s_3, \dots )$$
and let $a \in R$ be the left shift
$$(s_1, s_2, s_3, \dots) \mapsto (s_2, s_3, s_4, \dots).$$
Then $aub = 1$, since this composition has the effect of shifting a sequence to the right, deleting its first term (harmlessly, since it is now $0$), then shifting it back to the left.

I see. That's a good catch! I understood the linear combination aspect of $RuR$, but I think I got sidetracked referencing the proof for the case in which $R$ is commutative (in this instance, we could deduce that there would need exist $a\in R$ such that $ua=1$ by distributivity). As far as algebras are concerned, I have yet to hit that part of the course. So most of what you provide there is still foreign, but otherwise this is all very helpful!

The word "algebra" above is not essential, you could replace it with "ring" everywhere. And you're welcome!

@JAG131: I've also edited in some comments about the second error.
